# Changing gender pronouns interactively

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, design-patterns, nlp

I'm creating a 'choose your own adventure' type page for a project, where the user selects multiple values from option lists on the page, and their choices affect the rest of the page. This is in html/javascript, but I'm happy to adopt a decent pattern from another language if anyone's got one (or implement server-side via ajax if that's easier).

My current solution is to enclose all variable text in `<span>`s so that they can be picked up by the code. But it's ugly, especially when there are multiple overlapping changes.

Example:

```
html:
<p>Alice was a 
<select id="behave">
  <option value="good">good</option>
  <option value="naughty">naughty</option>
</select> 
<span class="boygirl">girl</span>.
 <span class="plotelement1">
  <span class="HeShe">She</span> was constantly being told off by 
  <span class="hisher">her</span> <span class="mainparent">mother</span>
 </span>.
</p>

js:
function genderChange(){
  var newgender = $("#gender").val();
  if(newgender == "male"){
    $(".heshe").text("he");
    $(".HeShe").text("He");
    $(".himher").text("him");
  } else {
    $(".heshe").text("she");
    $(".HeShe").text("She");
    $(".himher").text("her");
  }
}
function changeBehaviour(){
  switch($("#behave").val()){
  case "good":{
    $(".plotelement1").html('<span class="HeShe">She</span> made <span class="hisher">her</span> parents proud of <span class="himher">her</span> and they told <span class="himher">her</span> all the time how good <span class="heshe">she</span> was.');
    break;
  }
  default:{
    $(".plotelement1").html('<span class="HeShe">She</span> was constantly being told off by <span class="hisher">her</span> <span class="mainparent">mother</span>');
  }
  }
genderChange();
}
```

See? ugly and painful. How do I do this better?

Answer (score 0):

The way you approached it is somewhat good, but basically the problem you have is just that there are errors in your Js Code, The Corrected one is 
You can View the working version of it here http://jsfiddle.net/9zeD9/

```
<p>
    <select id="gender">
        <option value="male">male</option>
        <option value="female">female</option>
    </select>
    Alice was a 
    <select id="behave">
        <option value="good">good</option>
        <option value="naughty">naughty</option>
    </select> 
    <span class="boygirl">girl
    </span>. 
    <span class="plotelement1">
        <span class="HeShe">She</span> was constantly being told off by 
        <span class="hisher">her</span> 
        <span class="mainparent">mother</span>
    </span>.
</p>

<script>
function genderChange(){
  var newgender = $("#gender").val();
  if(newgender == "male"){
    $(".heshe").html("he");
    $(".HeShe").html("He");
    $(".himher").html("him");
    $(".hisher").html("his");
  } else {
    $(".heshe").textContent = "she";
    $(".HeShe").textContent = "She";
    $(".himher").textContent = "her";
    $(".hisher").html("her");
  }
}
$(function(){
        changeBehaviour();//      These 2 lines run after loading the whole page.
        genderChange();   //    

    $("#gender").change(function(){
        changeBehaviour();//    Change the behaviours first
        genderChange();   //    Then change the gender as the behaviour code has   
                          //    gender's span like ".hisher" so this has to be the
                          //    order.
    });
    $("#behave").change(function(){
      changeBehaviour();
      genderChange();
    })
});
function changeBehaviour(){
  switch($("#behave").val()){
  case "good":{
    $(".plotelement1").html('<span class="HeShe">She</span> made <span class="hisher">her</span> parents proud of <span class="himher">her</span> and they told <span class="himher">her</span> all the time how good <span class="heshe">she</span> was.');
    break;
  }
  default:{
    $(".plotelement1").html('<span class="HeShe">She</span> was constantly being told off by <span class="hisher">her</span> <span class="mainparent">mother</span>');
  }
}
}
</script>
```

PS:
Since You are using Jquery, to change the contents of any tag use,

```
$(".hisher").html("his")
```

Comment: Thanks for the corrections, I've edited the original, which was caught halfway between a conversion from plain js to jQuery and had bad syntax. It doesn't answer the question though ;)

Comment: What do you want , JQuery solves your problem right ? Just call the Behaviourchange before gender change, so this will work as you desired

Answer (score 0):

Very late post, but I had the same question and couldn't find any other answer.  I thought I'd share my answer in case anyone is looking in the future.  Five lines if you take out the comments, but admittedly not as readable as nested if/else or switch case statements.  It is faster based on the testing I did with Chrome, though we're talking the difference between 0.0089ms and 0.0131ms.  Working JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mjblay/4q0yjxoj/83/).

HTML:

```
<div id="female">
  <p id="HE" ></p>
  <p id="CAPHIS" ></p>
</div>
<div id="male">
  <p id="HIS" ></p>
  <p id="CAPHIM" ></p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function getPronoun(gender, id) {
  // array of pronouns to find
  var pronouns = ["she", "her", "her", "he", "his", "him"];

  // array of the last two letters of incoming pronouns in id parameter
  var ids = ["HE", "IS", "IM"];

  // get the index of the ids array matching the last two letters of id parameter
  var index = ids.indexOf(id.slice(-2));

  // if gender parameter is male, add 3 to the index
  index = gender == 'male' ? index + 3 : index;

  // use index to select the proper pronoun from the pronouns array
  // and capitalize it if CAP is present in the id parameter
  return id.indexOf('CAP') > -1 ?  cap(pronouns[index]) : pronouns[index];
}

function cap(input) {
  return input.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + input.substr(1);
}
```

Caveat: how you feed gender and id from your HTML/script is up to you.  This just demonstrates a way of mapping a generic pronoun to a specific pronoun based on several variables.